# Circular Queue using Dynamic Array

Tags: data-structures, queue, circular-buffer

I'm learning data structures from a "Fundamentals of Data structures in C" by Sahni. In the topic, Circular Queue using Dynamic Array, the author has mentioned below point,

> Let *capacity* be the initial capacity of the circular queue,We must
>   first increase the size of the array using realloc,this will copy
>   maximum of capacity elements on to the new array. To get a proper
>   circular queue configuration, we must slide elements in the right
>   segment(i.e, elements A and B) to the right end of the array(refer
>   diagram 3.7.d). The array doubling and the slide to the right together
>   copy at most **2 * *capacity* -2 elements**.

I understand array doubling copies at most capacity elements. But how does array doubling and slide to right copy at most **2 * capacity -2 elements**??
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Let us try to justify worst case scenario:**

For a queue with `capacity = N`, there are maximum `N-1 elements` present in the queue.

So, when we double the queue size, we need to copy all these N-1 elements to new queue, and at max there can be N-1 shifts(for elements).

So in total, 2*(N-1) = 2*N - 2